# Inverse matrix error

Tags: julia

I would like to do the inverse of matrix or number by multiplyig a vector with its trasposed but it gives me an error.

```
v=[1,2,3]           
inv(v'*v)

`inv` has no method matching inv(::Array{Int64,1})
while loading In[45], in expression starting on line 2
```

I would like to obtain a number or a square matrix at the end.
I do not want to use pinv function because i need to do further manipulations and i need exactly a number or a square matrix.
How to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`v` is a 3-element vector and `v'*v` is a 1-element vector:

```
julia> v = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> v'*v
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 14
```

You cannot invert a vector. If you want to compute the scalar dot product of `v` with itself, you can use the `dot` function and then invert it using `inv`:

```
julia> dot(v,v)
14

julia> inv(dot(v,v))
0.07142857142857142
```

Comment: If i have instead [1,2,3]*[1 2 3], so column*row i should have matrix...how i can face this?

Comment: The matrix obtained from multiplying a column-vector with row-vector is rank-one, hence singular and has no inverse. What do you want to invert in that case precisely?

Comment: I'd like to find inv(G' * G) where in general G is an m x p vector. In most, but not all, cases p=1 so I'm getting this error as well. It's quite the annoyance that Julia doesn't handle inverting a 1x1 vector in stride.

Comment: That operation works just fine if G is a matrix. In your example G is a vector, which is a different situation.

Answer (score 0):

This comes long after the question was asked, but maybe it is useful for someone. To elaborate a little:

- `[1, 2, 3]` is a vector or one-dimensional  (of type `Array{Int64,1}` or `Vector{Int64}`)
- `[1 2 3]` is a 1x3 matrix (of type `Array{Int64,2}`)
- `[1 2 3]'` is (is essence) a 3x1 matrix (of type `Array{Int64,2}`). This is not quite right, it is really a lazy (non-evaluated) version of it, but it will behave as it should

So what you want to achieve can be done as follows:

```
v = [1 2 3]
display(v' * v)
inv(v' * v)
```

This fails now for the right reason :-), i.e., the 3x3 matrix is not invertible.

BTW, you can convert a vector `v` (of type `Vector{T}` and length `n`) into an n×1-array of type `Array{T,2}` with `hcat(v)`.